# How To Fix UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_NOT_DONE

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, ssl, nginx

I have seen several answers to similar errors, but not my specific error.  The best example is Remy's answer to [UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_FLAG_NOT_TRUSTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945581/unity-tlsexception-handshake-failed-unitytls-x509verify-flag-not-trusted)

My error is as follows: `TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_NOT_DONE`

- Web API Node.js / MongoDB
- NGINX with CertBot
- SSL LetsEncrypt with Chained Certs in fullchain.pem

NGINX default

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on #managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privatekey.pem # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem # managed by Certbot
```

As per Unity Docs I used the `CertificateHandler` class

```
    internal class RequestCertificate : CertificateHandler
{

    private static string PUB_KEY = "SOME public key";


    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData);
        string pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
        if (pk.Equals(PUB_KEY))
        {
            Debug.Log("Validate Certificate");

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Validate Certificate");

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

My Register Method

```
protected IEnumerator Register()
{
    List<IMultipartFormSection> wwwForm = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    wwwForm.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("name", uName.text));
    wwwForm.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("email", uEmail.text));
    wwwForm.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("screenName", uScreenName.text));
    wwwForm.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("password", uConPass.text));

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(EndPointManager.API_URL + "users/store-user", wwwForm);
    www.certificateHandler = new RequestCertificate();
    Debug.Log(www.certificateHandler.GetHashCode());
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error); // OUTPUT: Unable to complete SSL connection
        debugText.text += $"\n HTTP ERROR: {www.error} \n";
    }
    else
    {
        debugText.text += "Success";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This had nothing to do with the certificate authority, or NGINX.  I decided to set up a front end form to test this error in Chrome and as soon as I did, the answer hit me in the face.  I forgot to set environment variables on the production server and got `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.  Since Unity returned an error that I wasn't familiar with, I didn't know how to handle it.

I had my app.js file looking for the `process.env.NODE_ENV` so it could set `protocol = 'https'` but hadn't set it.  As soon as I did Node.js used `https.createServer(app)` instead of `http.crateServer(app)` and all is well.